# Azure docker containers time shift (ntp not in sync)

Tags: azure, docker

We have a few docker containers deployed in Azure `container_group` with `os_type` set to `Linux`

What we notice(from time to time) is that the datetime of the docker containers are not in sync with any ntp and the datetime is shifted. Sometimes we notice shifts of > 15 seconds.

Any idea how to fix this one?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_group
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/time-sync